# Proper way to destroy a file chooser dialog in pygtk for python

Tags: python, pygtk

I've been trying to use gtk to create a folder choosing dialog, but  I can't figure out how to make the dialog close. Here is the code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import time

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a folder", None,
Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER,
    (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
    "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

response = dialog.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print("Select clicked")
    print("Folder selected: " + dialog.get_filename())
elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
    print("Cancel clicked")

dialog.destroy()
time.sleep(5)
```

I understand that I need to call gtk.main() in some way for it to work properly, but I can't figure out how.
I've been using the last example from http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html but that has a box at the beginning that I don't know how to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a nicer way, but I usually do it like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib

def run_dialog(_None):
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a folder", None,
    Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
        "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("Select clicked")
        print("Folder selected: " + dialog.get_filename())
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        print("Cancel clicked")

    dialog.destroy()
    Gtk.main_quit()


Gdk.threads_add_idle(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, run_dialog, None)
Gtk.main()
```

This will call the `run_dialog` function as soon as the mainloop starts, which will display the dialog and then quit.

**UPDATE:** If you want to enclose that code in a function that returns the selected folder, you'll need to save the path to a non-local variable:

```
def run_folder_chooser_dialog():
    result= []

    def run_dialog(_None):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a folder", None,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            "Select", Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            result.append(dialog.get_filename())
        else:
            result.append(None)

        dialog.destroy()
        Gtk.main_quit()


    Gdk.threads_add_idle(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, run_dialog, None)
    Gtk.main()
    return result[0]
```

In python 3, you can use `nonlocal result` and `result= dialog.get_filename()` instead of the ugly list reference.

Comment: No there is another problem. How do I get the function to actually return the value of the selected folder as a string?

Comment: `return dialog.get_filename()`?

Comment: Yes but when I try to get it to return the value outside of the function, the loop either continues forever or I get an error message that gtk.main_quit doesn't have a loop to quit.

Comment: If I put the "return dialog.get_filename()" before the Gtk.main_quit() the value is returned and the main quit never executes and the loop runs again, and if I put the return after the quit, the loop quits before the return which gives me nothing returned. I think I need to move the Gtk.main_quit() to somewhere else, so the function both returns the value outside the loop AND quits the loop. I am using a workaround with declaring a Global variable and saving the information there, but that seems icky.

Comment: @Johan: Ah, I see what you're trying to do. Answer updated, though it's not much better than using a global variable.

Comment: Thanks another bunch! The list option is less ugly than the global at least, I'll stick to that one for now!